# Get key from value with this node.js dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, collections, collectionsjs

I am using this node.js collection module. 
http://www.collectionsjs.com/

I would like to get the key from value inside a dictionary. Here is my code;

```
"use strict";
var Dict = require("collections/dict");

var Data_type = new Dict(
    {
        "00": "DATA_NOT",
        "01": "DATA_SENSOR",
        "02": "DATA_SENSOR2",
        "03": "DATA_SENSOR3",
    });
```

Getting the value from key is easy. `Data_type.get("00");` will return `DATA_NOT`. However, I am encountering problem in getting the key from value. Preferably, I would like to do something like  `Data_type.getKey("DATA_NOT");` and have it return `"00"`. Any other methods are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

will you have more than one same values in the dict ?
another possible methods could use `map()` function in collectionjs

```
mapDict = [];
dict.map(function(v,k) { '
    if (v === "DATA_NOT") { 
    mapDict.add(v,k); 
    }
});

mapDict.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The underscore way:

```
_.findKey(Data_type, DATA_NOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If underscore or lodash `findKey` method doesn't work for your dict, then you could iterate through your dict's [keys](http://www.collectionsjs.com/method/keys), i.e. `Data_Type.keys()` and find your value